# Trying to find the MSI product code for Java 8 Update 25 in to work with WSUS Package Publisher

Tags: java, windows-installer, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-users

I'm trying to create a 3rd party custom update through WSUS Package Publisher however I can't manage to get the MSI code for Java as there is no MSI installer to use MSIReader on.  If anyone knows how I can find this code then it would be much appreciated.  It's managing to make me look bad as a Sys Admin at work.

Cheers,
Glympse.

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions :

- Install the product and search in : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- Or to be aware that Oracle always used the same schema for these MSI Product code

Java 8 : 26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f8**32**1**8**0**25**f0 = 32 Bit - Java 8u25

Java 7 : 26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F8**32**1**7**0**45**FF = 32 Bit - Java 7u45

Answer (score 0):

Ah!

Never mind I found the answer myself.  I installed the version I wanted to publish on a laptop then searched "ModifyPath" in the registry until I found the correct software in this case Java 8 update 25.  Hope this helps if anyone else has this problem.

FYI the following are the 64 ans 32 bit MSI codes for Java 8 update 25

32 BIT - 26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f83218025f0

64 BIT - 26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f86418025f0

Cheers,
Glympse.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to run

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product
```

Which will return e.g.

```
IdentifyingNumber : {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180121F0}
Name              : Java 8 Update 121 (64-bit)
Vendor            : Oracle Corporation
Version           : 8.0.1210.13
Caption           : Java 8 Update 121 (64-bit)
```