# Java 8 MSI Product Code

Tags: java, windows-installer, product

Does anyone know where there may be a list off all the Java version 8 Product Codes? Ive looked online and all the lists only go up to java 7.... I am tyring to create a script that uninstalls all previous versions of java but need the product codes to do so. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Trying to find the MSI product code for Java 8 Update 25 in to work with WSUS Package Publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527102/trying-to-find-the-msi-product-code-for-java-8-update-25-in-to-work-with-wsus-pa) possible duplicate with this, it should have any information you need.

Basically, oracle uses the same naming scheme for all of their products with only a few characters changed.

Comment: Thanks! that gave me all of the help that i needed!